# how to prevent popover from overlapping the navigation toolbar?

Tags: ios, ipad, uipopovercontroller, popover, cgrect

In my iPad app, I present a popover from tableview editing style insert control.

how can I prevent my popover from overlapping the navigation bar when the anchor is in a high position?
sadly, i'm not allowed to post an image.

the CGrect in my code seems to only move the popover anchor and the size, but not the relation between them. (or: where the anchor is on the popover frame)

Any hint much appreciated!

in commitEditingStyle if UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert:

```
popOverController.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(320.0, 400.0);

CGRect rect = CGRectMake(cell.bounds.origin.x+200, cell.bounds.origin.y+10, 50, 30);
    [popOverController presentPopoverFromRect:rect inView:cell permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft animated:YES];
 }
```